# Created an event trigger in Postgres but doesn't show up?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is on Postgres 10.3 under AWS RDS.

In the excerpts below, I am using just public for the search_path.

I am trying to adapt an existing event trigger, defined like this:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER update_last_modified ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mll_audit();
```

Which was created some time in the past and shows up like so:

```
=> \df *modified*
                                List of functions
 Schema |         Name         | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type   
--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------
 public | update_last_modified | trigger          |                     | trigger
```

The new trigger will call a new procedure, but for the time being, I'm just trying to verify that I can create one:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER deltest_update_last_modified ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mll_audit();
```

This creates fine, apparently, but doesn't show up:

```
=> CREATE EVENT TRIGGER deltest_update_last_modified ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mll_audit();
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER

rwe=> \df *deltest*modified*
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)

=> \df *modified*
                                List of functions
 Schema |   rwe=> \df *deltest*modified*
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)

=> \df *modified*
                                List of functions
 Schema |         Name         | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type   
--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------
 public | update_last_modified | trigger          |                     | trigger
(1 row)

=> select proname from pg_proc where proname like '%modified%';
       proname        
----------------------
 update_last_modified
(1 row)
```

If I try to recreate without dropping it, it errors that it already exists:

```
=> CREATE EVENT TRIGGER deltest_update_last_modified ON ddl_command_end
->     WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
->     EXECUTE PROCEDURE mll_audit();
ERROR:  event trigger "deltest_update_last_modified" already exists
```

I feel like I must be missing something basic. I just want to create this in the public schema.

Answer (score 1):

`\df` lists functions, not event triggers. `\dy` is used to list event triggers. You just happen to *also* have a function called `update_last_modified` (perhaps unintentionally?).